# Multiple headers, How to get different margin_top value for different pages

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

In my application, i need create a document pdf in wkhtmltopdf.
There are more than one pages in my document pdf. I generate dynamicly a file html static for header_html specified to the first page and another header_html specified for the rest of page.

My question is the two headers are not the same height:[image]

[image]

How can i get margin_top value dynamicly for each page ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Always search solution in several days past, i found that the value margin-top can't be modified once it was defined.

Comment: But you can control display header or not by javascript which is done in html static file.

Comment: Have you found the solution eventually? I just have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want make your first page is different from the others pages. you can use `cover page` like:

```
wkhtmltopdf -H cover cover.html ...
```

[doc](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately,  it's not answer for me.